# mapping oid attribute names to friendly names in onelogin

Tags: php, symfony, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I am using Symfony in php with this bundle: https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle

That uses the onelogin php-saml toolkit: https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

My IDP on authentication returns attributes that need mapping from oid to a friendly name

```
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">58690</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">mytestemail@gmail.com</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
```

This works fine if I use the oid name in the symfony bundles config and don't have friendly names on. However I do want to map these to uid and email. I have used simplesamlphp and it supplied as class for mapping these values but have not found similar in onelogin php-saml so I think I need to manually map them.

I thought I needed to supply an attribute consumer service but this hasn't changed anything

```
## ...
sp:
        entityId: 'http://test.local/saml/metadata'
        assertionConsumerService:
            url: 'http://test.local/saml/acs'
            binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST'
        attributeConsumingService:
            serviceName: 'SP test'
            serviceDescription: 'Test Service'
            requestedAttributes:
                - name: 'urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1'
                  isRequired: true
                  friendlyName: 'uid'
                - name: 'urn:oid:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1'
                  isRequired: true
                  friendlyName: 'email'
## etc...
```

Anyone know how to do this in onelogin / in the plugin? Am I on the right track with regards to onelogin at least?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the friendly names referenced in onelogin are referring to a possible field in the attributes returned by the IDP that you could then choose to use.

My IDP doesn't do this so It is down to me to map the attributes.

Mapping oid to/from ldap names is a feature of simplesamlphp.

No attribute mapping is supplied in onelogin but of course can be done in your own code.